# How do I get all merge requests from Gitlab Api?

Tags: php, symfony, gitlab

Currently I am trying to integrate Gitlab in my project and the problem I am facing is this. Documentation says that endpoint `/api/v4/merge_request?scope=all` should return all merge requests I can have access to. But what I am getting is only 20-21 MR(should be over 100). And I have access to 100 over MR. Any help would be helpful
my method is below

```php
public function getMerges() {
      $url = $this->url."/api/v4/merge_requests?scope=all";
      return $this->request($url, $this->auth);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Requests to list endpoints are paginated by default, as documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/index.html#offset-based-pagination

You have iterate all the pages to obtain the complete list. The number of pages is returned in the `x-total-pages` header.